# Asset library won't work with my ik rig

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics, asset-browser, library

So this is my first time working with the new pose library so maybe I’m doing something wrong but when trying to make a pose with a custom ik rig I setup it won't save the pose it just does nothing. When I try it with a basic armature it works so does this asset library just not work with ik rigs?

Comment: The short answer is: yes, the PoseLib works with IK rigs. A more detailed answer to the question is unfortunately not possible since you have revealed almost no details. What do you mean by "it just does nothing"? Has the pose been created? Does an action with keyframes exist? Which bones do you select?

Comment: By nothing I mean a pose was created in the asset browser but when I click on it or apply pose to the selected bones it does not apply the pose to the armature. There was a keyframe on the timeline.

Comment: Hm, ... if there is an action with only 1 frame and the correct keyframe (=the pose), and you have selected the correct bones then it should work. I've done poses with Rigify that has IK and FK controls and both types work in poses. Can you share a demo file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N70EPXSPC3ukiKsZITPSn1ZtjfdpN8kt/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you use Blender 3.5? In this version, the UI got revamped and the *Apply Pose, Blend Pose*, *Select Bones*, and *Flip Pose* buttons are now hidden in the context menu. You still can apply the pose with a double click in the assert browser or a single click in the side panel of the 3D viewport. You need to be in *Pose* mode and have selected the bones. It works for me with your model and I can pose an example if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's working now I'm pretty sure I was doing everything you mentioned before well whatever it's working now thanks a lot!